# SNMP for HP switch

Tags: python-3.x

so let say I ran this command to get me the code verison of any device :

snmpwalk -v 2c -c PUBLIC 192.168.0.5  .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.2.2.1.2

so I have the result like this :

revision KB.16.02.0014, ROM KB.16.01.0006 (/ws/swbuildm/rel_spokane_qaoff/code/build/bom(swbuildm_rel_spokane_qaoff_rel_spokane))

I need to add function to my code to manupulate the result to revision KB.16.02.0014 only ??? I dont need:  ROM KB.16.01.0006 (/ws/swbuildm/rel_spokane_qaoff/code/build/bom(swbuildm_rel_spokane_qaoff_rel_spokane))

any suggestions

Comment: lets say x = revision KB.16.02.0014, ROM KB.16.01.0006 (/ws/swbuildm/rel_spokane_qaoff/code/build/bom(swbuildm_rel_spokane_qaoff_rel_spokane))     how can I change the X value to revision KB.16.02.0014  only  ?

Comment: How is this python related? Are you running `snmpwalk` from the command line? If so, what OS?

Comment: right now  Im running SNMP walk in Linux server Ubuntu ...but I can insert that OID in another Python code to get me the same results ..

Comment: If you want to remove everything after the comma, google "python string split by comma"?